# How can I make the Button click Event

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I Would like to create a little Game. Now my Problem is that nothing is happening when I'm pressing the Button:

Main Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def Aufgabe():
     os.system('python Test.py')

def Wahrheit():
     os.system('python Test.py')

master= Tk()
master.geometry("200x60")

master.configure(bg='light blue')

Button(master, text="Aufgabe", command= print(Aufgabe)).place(x=20, y=20)
Button(master, text="Wahrheit", command="Wahrheit").place(x=100, y=20)

mainloop()
```

Test.py Code:

```
import random
print(random.randint(1,6))
```

Comment: Did you mean `Button(master, text="Aufgabe", command=Aufgabe...` and `Button(master, text="Wahrheit", command=Wahrheit...`?

Comment: Yeah Sorry ....